# How to find if Azure File exists on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express

I'm using the azure file storage, and using express JS to write a backend to render the contents stored in the azure file storage.

I am writing the code based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-share/shareserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest

```js
const { ShareServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-file-share");

const account = "<account>";
const accountKey = "<accountkey>";

const credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
const serviceClient = new ShareServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.file.core.windows.net`,
  credential
);

const shareName = "<share name>";
const fileName = "<file name>";

// [Node.js only] A helper method used to read a Node.js readable stream into a Buffer
async function streamToBuffer(readableStream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
      chunks.push(data instanceof Buffer ? data : Buffer.from(data));
    });
    readableStream.on("end", () => {
      resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
    });
    readableStream.on("error", reject);
  });
}
```

And you can view the contents through

```js
const downloadFileResponse = await fileClient.download();
const output = await streamToBuffer(downloadFileResponse.readableStreamBody)).toString()
```

Thing is, I only want to find if the file exists and not spend time downloading the entire file, how could I do this?

I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-share/shareserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest
to see if the file client class has what I want, but it doesn't seem to have methods useful for this.

Comment: Just call this URL with a Bearer token - `https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydirectorypath/myfile?comp=metadata`. If you get a 200 OK back, you have a file, else file does not exist - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file-metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [`@azure/storage-file-share (version 12.x)`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-file-share) Node package, there's an [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-share/sharefileclient?view=azure-node-latest#exists_FileExistsOptions_) method in [`ShareFileClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-share/sharefileclient?view=azure-node-latest). You can use that to find if a file exists or not. Something like:

```
const fileExists = await fileClient.exists();//returns true or false.
```